# GUI Interface For Command Line Input/Output

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction for a project I would like to do. My intention is simple, to have a GUI that allows a user to input a string, that string fills into a pre-determined line of command line text, runs through the command line and returns what is printed on the command line screen. I've been leaning toward using Python for this but I am still not sure about the syntax that will accomplish even the first part, where a user will input a string and that string will run through the line of command line text. Any sort of input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: python 2 or 3? .

Comment: I'm truly not sure, I'm new to the python world. Would one be better than the other for this project?

Comment: You can use python 3. Check your python version by typing `python -V` in the command line

Comment: It appears that i have 2.7.10 installed currently. If 3 is better, I can get that put on instead.

Comment: On some platforms `python` is always Py2 and if Py3 is installed the command for that is `python3`. If you are only just getting started, definitely target Py3.

Comment: Maybe you should check out gooey: https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey

Answer (score 3):

## This is a simple GUI using tkinter for python

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk        # python v3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk        # python v2

# This function is called when the submit button is clicked
def submit_callback(input_entry):
    print("User entered : " + input_entry.get())
    return None


#######################  GUI ###########################
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x150')       #Set window size

# Heading
heading = tk.Label(root, text="A simple GUI")
heading.place(x = 100, y = 0)


input_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter some text")
input_label.place(x = 0, y = 50)

input_entry = tk.Entry(root)
input_entry.place(x = 100, y = 50)


submit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = lambda: submit_callback(input_entry))
submit_button.place(x = 200, y = 90)
root.mainloop()
#############################################################
```

Answer (score 2):

Developing a GUI is a big project for python beginners, there are several possibilities to do this. If you want to seriously develop GUI applications in Python I would recommend you to try Qt4 or Qt5 via pyside or pyqt. You may need one or more tutorials and maybe some problems to get your first working GUI applications, but you will be able to build any kind of professional cross-platform applications using this libraries.

With running command line text, you mean system commands or python commands? If you want to run system commands, I would recommend you to write a short python script, that handles user input (within the python commandline) and passes it to the system using subprocess (`from subprocess import call`).

If you have done your first simple textform in pyqt and the script that handles user input try to connect them by wrapping the Qt application around the commandline script. If you just looking for a quick and dirty solution there are several libraries, that support some easy to setup GUI frames or webinterfaces (to run in the browser on the local machine). But if you are a programming beginner I would highly recommend to split this into twor or three minor projects, to keep the frustration level low ;).

Edit Python2 vs Python3: pyqt and pyside are available for both python2 and python3 (as the most, but not all libraries) so your choice between py2 and py3 is on your own. The Syntax is almost the same (except the print() command), but the libraries you install are only working in the version you installed them.
If you are working on a linux machine you can easily install both versions in parallel if you want to make sure the right version is called you can specify the command such as `python2` or `python3` instead of running the default with `python`

Edit2 handle user input:

```
from subprocess import check_output

def predefined_command(user_input):
    command = ['net', 'user', '/domain', user_input]
    answer = check_output(command, args)
    decoded = answer.decode('utf8')
    return answer
```

Comment: My goal is to take an input from a user like (xxxxxx) and that would go into a pre-determined string for a command line command that reads ''net user /domain xxxxxx''. This would then spit out a bunch of information about the user that I want to then have show in the GUI instead of in the command prompt. I hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: If you want to use tkinter you can use the code that Stack posted (which is maybe a bit more fastforward than using pyqt). To run the command you can use your own function instead of the `print('user input: ...')` in the callback handler. I will give an example by editing my answer.

Comment: For 3.6 and up you want `subprocess.run()`

Comment: yeah the `run()` method was added in 3.5 or 3.6 but what are the advantages compared to the `check_output()` method which returns the output directly without any need to catch it using Pipes or whatever?